# Display timestamp variable in Twig Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

How to print a variable in twig html file such as for date:
`{{ timeComment|date('Y-m-d') }}`

I've tried `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: it should work, what does it print ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the **current** datetime, you can do this:

```
{{ "now"|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html for details.